# Android : build.gradle problem after add sdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've add the SDK to the builder.gradle like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.kontaktio:sdk:3.0.2'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But it return an error

> ERROR: Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.kontaktio:sdk:3.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: You're adding compile dependencies in the wrong block. You need to add it to the app-level build.gradle and not the root build.gradle.

Comment: @Zoe is correct, `dependencies {
        compile 'com.kontaktio:sdk:3.0.2'
    }` must be inside *module* build.gradle instead *project* build.gradle

Comment: I'm new for Android, please help me to find the build.gradle on app-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the following block from your **project** build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.kontaktio:sdk:3.0.2'
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

to your **module** build.gradle (usually **app** module).

---

your **project** build.gradle dependencies block must use `classpath` instead of `compile`. Your project build.gradle should be something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please take a look [Configure your build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Now I can fix this, my app build.gradle is missing.
I've created a new project and set up again, it's working fine.

Comment: Glad that it helps you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

They change the 'compile' into 'implementation' on latest gradle, so you need to change

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.kontaktio:sdk:3.0.2'
}
```

to

```
 dependencies {
    implementation 'com.kontaktio:sdk:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: That's just half the problem. Also: `They change the 'compile' into 'implementation' on latest gradle, so you need to change` - this is far from new. Implementation has been preferred for a while